# VSCode Extension API - on scroll

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to detected when scrolling in the VSCode extension API. The only available functions I see are:

```ts
onDidChangeActiveTextEditor: Event<TextEditor>

onDidChangeTextEditorOptions: Event<TextEditorOptionsChangeEvent>

onDidChangeTextEditorSelection: Event<TextEditorSelectionChangeEvent>

onDidChangeTextEditorViewColumn: Event<TextEditorViewColumnChangeEvent>

onDidChangeVisibleTextEditors: Event<TextEditor[]>

onDidChangeWindowState: Event<WindowState>

onDidCloseTerminal: Event<Terminal>
```

I can file this as a feature request. But is there any way to circumvent this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS Code now has an api for this: `window.onDidChangeTextEditorVisibleRanges`

This event is fired with an `TextEditorVisibleRangesChangeEvent` object:

```ts
export interface TextEditorVisibleRangesChangeEvent {
    /**
     * The text editor for which the visible ranges have changed.
     */
    textEditor: TextEditor;

    /**
     * The new value for the text editor's visible ranges.
     */
    visibleRanges: Range[];
}
```

VS Code's markdown preview uses this event to synchronize the scrolling of the editor with the markdown  preview.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I suspected. We will just have to wait and see